# GNU readline and the Alt key in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

GNU readline lets you move a word forward/backward using M-f and M-b (where M is usually the Alt key). But ever since upgrading to 12.04 it stopped working.

At first I tried disabling the "Key to show HUD" in Compiz, but it seems like that's not enough.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Terminal menu -> Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Enable menu access keys.

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Just to clarify, that option needs to be disabled.